# IF else Stored procedure confusion

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

This is a table

```
name a  b  c   normal loan status
abc  50 60 70               normal
bcd  50 50 50               loan
```

what i want first is to get total of values of columns a,b and c in accordance with their status.. meaning; total amount of name with status normal  should come under normal column,and of status loan should come under loan column..

i should get abc's total 50+60+70 in normal
and bcd's total 50+50+50 in loan

how do i do that ??

i tried if else in SP , but cant seem to be getting it

Comment: I don't know what `IF` `ELSE` has to do with this but if you're working with SQL Server, you might want to look at [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below is what you need. The below query is a standard ANSI query:

```
SELECT    name
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'normal' THEN (a + b + c) ELSE 0 END)  AS normal
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'loan' THEN (a + b + c) ELSE 0 END)  AS loan
          ,status

FROM     yourTable

GROUP BY name, status
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
name    normal  loan    status
bcd      0      150     loan
abc      180    0       normal
```

As per your requirement in the comment to update the existing rows:

```
UPDATE  yourTable
SET normal = CASE WHEN status = 'normal' THEN (a + b + c) ELSE 0 END,
loan = CASE WHEN status = 'loan' THEN (a + b + c) ELSE 0 END
FROM yourTable
```

Please note that you need to update the table every time you insert new record or to change the original `INSERT` statement to include those columns as well.

Comment: I need to insert into the existing columns, dont want to create new ones dynamically..

Comment: @Shabarish Ail I have updated the answer to include the `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

In single select you can make it.

Try

```
SELECT *,(CASE WHEN [status]='normal' THEN [a]+[b]+[c] ELSE null END) as normal,(CASE WHEN [status]='loan' THEN [a]+[b]+[c] ELSE null END) as loan FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I need to insert into the existing columns, dont want to create new ones dynamically..

Comment: Then you have to create Trigger for that table with insert action